# The command to switch to alert does not work in this case

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing an automation and at a certain moment an alert appears, but I can't use the switch.to it, it doesn't find any alert, even in interactive mode.

[image]

Does anyone know another tool or know how to get through this alert? He just needs to click on '' Ok '', but confirm doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try passing it an "enter" keypress?

Comment: I think the alert is in another window so Selenium doesn't see it. You will probably need to send the enter key using win32com or similar library.

Comment: Got it, do you know any code to press Enter on this lib? 
Selenium's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is not a web alert but a windows one. You can solve this by automatically tell what certificate to use. This can be done from registries.

https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::AutoSelectCertificateForUrls

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31766971)